# HTML forms with PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

The problem I am having is that I would like when the option is selected and the submit button is pressed, the table in MySQL should be updated. After the update the new table should be displayed on the form. This is a school grade table and the teacher should be able to change the grades. I can not seem to make it work.

```
$courseSct = "SELECT username, courseName, grade, gradeID FROM Courses\n"
                    . "JOIN Grades\n"
                    . "ON courses.courseId = Grades.courseId";
    $result = $connection->query($courseSct);
    $rows = $result->num_rows;



    for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
    {
        $result->data_seek($j);
        $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

        echo 'User Name: ' . "\t\t" . $row[0];
        echo "\t" . 'Course Name:' . "\t\t" . $row[1] . "\t\t";       
        echo "\t" . 'Grade:' . "\t" . $row[2]; 
        echo '<select name="grade" size="1" id="' . $row[3] . '">
            <option value="select">Select</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            <option value="F">F</option>
            <option value="I">I</option>
        </select><br>';
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $courseSct = "UPDATE Grades SET grade=\'$row[2]\' "
                       . "WHERE id=\'$row[3]\'";
            $result = $connection->query($courseSct);
            //$row[2] = '$row[3]';
            //echo "This is the updated grades table <br><br>";
        }
```

Comment: Please also add your HTML form to your question.

Answer (score 1):

some mistakes:

you don't need `\n`, simply do it like this:

```
$courseSct = "SELECT username, courseName, grade, gradeID
FROM Courses
INNER JOIN Grades
ON courses.courseId = Grades.courseId";
```

also `num_rows` returns number of rows, what you want is `field_count`.
also you don't need the escape character `\` for `' '` inside of `" "`..